# Убрать пробел после запятой в строке JS

Tags: javascript

У меня есть строка , допустим "1 777,97 2".
Мне нужно убрать пробелы после запятой, но чтобы пробелы перед запятой  - остались.
То есть результат нужен такой: "1 777,972"
Это строка, код пишу в JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let s_num = '1 777,97 2';

s_num = s_num.split(',').map((s, i) => i == 0 ? s : s.replace(/\s+/g, '')).join(',');

console.log(s_num);
```

Answer (score 2):

Также можно воспользоваться [Lookbehind assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#Other_assertions) позволяющей находить подстроку `x`, которой предшествует подстрока `y`

```js
let s_num = '1 777,97 2';

console.log(s_num.replace(/(?<=,.+)\s+/g, ''));
```